# hosting entire react application inside another react application landing page

Tags: reactjs, redux

we have some wrapped up SPA react application, we need to host it inside another react application landing page as well as many other stand alone react applications, what is the best way to achieve such behavior?

Comment: The same way you render React as an SPA. Create a container element in the SPA with a given `id` and use `ReactDOM.render()` to dump your other application inside it.

Comment: you will having two different reacts on your webpage, as compiled bundles of both SPA will contain React. Sometimes it can cause issues. So if you have the source code of both apps, combine them together and make one single app.